# Proper subsets of connected spaces and proper product

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $A$ be a proper subset of $X$ and $B$ a proper subset of $Y$. If $X,Y$ are connected. Show that

$X\times Y\backslash (A\times B)$ is connected.

***Lemma:*** Let $X$ be a space and $A_1,A_2...,A_n$ a finite sequence of connected subsets in $X$. If $A_j\cap A_{j+1}\neq \varnothing$ for each $j=1,2...,n-1$ then $A_1\cup A_2 \cup...A_n$ is connected.

My attempt:

Fix $a\in X\backslash A$ and fix $b\in Y\backslash B$..

Observe, $\{$ $a$ $\} \times Y$ and $X\times \{$ b $\}$  are connected. Let $x\in X\backslash A$ and$y\in Y\backslash B$. Put

$T_{xy}=(\{x \}\times Y)$ $\cup (X\times \{b\}) \cup (\{a\} \times Y$) $\cup$ $(X \times \{y \})$
Then, $T_{xy}$ is connected because of the above lemma. Put $T=\bigcup_{x\in X\backslash A}\bigcup_{y\in Y\backslash B} T_{xy}$ . Then, $T$ is connected because each $T_{xy}$ contains $(a,b)$ and each $T_{xy}$ is connected

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. But the lemma doesn't apply here since you don't have a finite (Or even it may not be enumerable) collection of connected subsets.

The lemma which applies here would be : 
Let, $X$ be a topological space and $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of connected subsets of $X$ such that $A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta} \neq \emptyset \forall \alpha, \beta$ then $\cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ is connected.

Comment: Sure, but my lecturer has presented the lemma as I have written it. `The sets in the union are each connected via homeomorphism, you have finite many which satisfy the conditions in the lemma when arranged appropriately. No?

Comment: The Lemma is correct but the family you are working on may be uncountable too. So, after clubbing too many of them you may not be able to make it a finite collection. So this Lemma is not useful here.

Comment: The finite many sets are  $\{$ $x$ $\}$ $\times Y$,  $X\times \{b\}$, $ \{a \} \times Y$, $X\times \{y\}$. I'm invoking the lemma on these sets Call $A_1=\{ x\} \times Y$ and ...

Comment: Yes but then you are taking union of all the $T_{xy}$ to conclude the result. I am saying that the result may not be applicable there.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, when I took the union and said its connected I meant via a well know lemma. Namely, if $X$ is connected and $(B_i)_i$ is a collection of connected subsets with a common member, then their union is connected

Comment: You can check on this space: $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R - \Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Please see what I wrote before this comment

Comment: Yup right. I just supplied a more general version of the Lemma you are using.

Comment: Aha, so provided my previous comment, is what I have written correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Have a very wonderful day

Comment: You are welcome. Let me add, a similar result (with all these Lemma) is true for path connected spaces. You may give it a try.

Comment: The lemma is for $T_{x,y}$ and is correctly used. So for any $x,y \in Z$ (the complement) we have a connected subset that contains both of them so $x$ is in the component of $y$ and as this is an equivalence relation, we're done: $Z$ is connected. We don't use a union lemma explicitly for the final step, but show all points are equivalent under the "component equivalence relation". @topologicalorientablesurface

Comment: @Henmon Brandmsa, your feedback is always really helpful and englightening. I just need to work out the details of what you have written a bit, I still haven’t learned about components.